# Mostrar elementos faltantes en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

Estoy con este tema sin resolver. Necesito mostrar la documentación presentada por un alumno y la documentacion que le falta presentar. Por ahora trae bien lo que ya presentó, con el tema de la faltante tengo el problema. Uso este foreach.

```
$documentacion = DB::table('doc_insts')->select('*')->get();
//Trae la documentacion cargada de un alumno
$doc_del_alumno = DB::table('alumnos')->where('dni',$dni)
                ->join('doc_alu_insts','alumno_id','=','alumnos.id')
                ->join('doc_insts','doc_alu_insts.documentacion_id','=','doc_insts.id')
                ->select('doc_alu_insts.*','alumnos.nombre','doc_insts.descripcion')->get();

$array_doc_presentada =  array();
$array_doc_necesaria =  array();



foreach ($documentacion as $key_doc_necesaria => $value_doc_necesaria) {
  foreach ($doc_del_alumno as $key_doc_presentada => $value_doc_presentada) {

    if ($value_doc_necesaria->id == $value_doc_presentada->documentacion_id) {
      array_push($array_doc_presentada, $value_doc_presentada);

    }
    else {
      array_push($array_doc_necesaria, $value_doc_necesaria);
    }
  }
}
```

En el array "array_doc_necesaria" en lugar de tener lo que falta, se carga de lo que ya tiene y lo que le falta.

Dejo los resultados que arroja:
[image: Solo los elementos #123 y #309 deben aparecer, y ademas se repiten]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: $array_doc_presentada si obtiene la información correcta?

Comment: Asi es, ese array lo carga perfectamente

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que devuelven las 2 consultas (`$documentacion` y `$doc_del_alumno`)?

Comment: Agregue lo que devuelven las consultas. Pienso que devuelve así por el propio bucle foreach, al no encontrar los valores coincidentes en el IF de un bucle en otro, los agrega a todos en $array_doc_necesaria cuado pasa por el ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de esta otra forma directamente usando eloquent:

```
$instituto_id = DB::table('alumnos')->where('dni',$dni)
                  ->Join('alu_carr_insts','alumnos.id','=','alu_carr_insts.alumno_id')
                  ->pluck('alu_carr_insts.instituto_id')->first();

$id_alumno = DB::table('alumnos')->where('dni',$dni)->pluck('id')->first();

$doc_faltante = DB::table('doc_insts')
               ->where('instituto_id',$instituto_id)
               ->whereNotIn('doc_insts.id',function ($query) use ($id_alumno, $instituto_id){ //Ver este USE
                   $query->select('documentacion_id')->from('doc_alu_insts')
                         ->where('instituto_id','=', $instituto_id)
                         ->where('alumno_id','=', $id_alumno);
                  })->get();
```

Comment: Este no es Eloquent directamente sino el query builder

Comment: Además con base en [answer], te recomendaría editar tus respuestas y agregar una explicacion